# Classifying spaces of a profinite groups  

Tags: classifying-spaces, at.algebraic-topology

As a topological group, a profinite group $G$ has a classifying space $BG$. On the other hand, since $G = \underleftarrow{\lim}\; G/U\;\;(U \le G$ open$)$ is an inverse limit of finite groups, we also have an inverse system $B(G/U)$ of topological spaces and can form the space $\underleftarrow{\lim}B(G/U)$.

**Question 1:** How do $BG$ and $\underleftarrow{\lim}B(G/U)$ relate ? Can we, for example say, that $\underleftarrow{\lim}B(G/U)$ is a classifying space for $G$ ?

**Question 2:** Are there futher results about classifying spaces of profinite groups ?

Comment: Even if it does not directly pertain to your question, I think the following would be good to look at: Gereon Quick sets up some good technology for working with profinite groups. He also makes it seem easy. http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gquick/HomfixedpointsforLT03182012.pdf

His other work might be of interest to you as well.

Answer (score 2):

The paper http://www.math.uiuc.edu/documenta/vol-13/17.pdf seems to be about this kind of thing.

Comment: The link is broken now. Probably it was to point to: Gereon Quick, "Profinite homotopy theory", Doc. Math. 13 (2008) 585-612 (https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.4082)

Comment: Maybe.  I don't remember.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of literature on classifying spaces of the $p$-adic integers. For instance, there are [two 45-year old "computations"](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1967-129-01/S0002-9947-1967-0212127-3/home.html) of the complex K-theory of the $p$-adic integers, resulting in two different answers. An explanation of why they are different, only found recently, is by considering a more refined notion of a classifying space, which is a uniform space well-defined up to uniform homotopy equivalence (see, for lack of a better account, subsection 1.4 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0346v1)).